# Drag & drop event for WinForms Form not Control

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, drag-and-drop, eventhandler

#### What I'm trying to do.

I have searching if there exists a drag&drop event for a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class without luck...

I was wondering if there is an optimized way of doing this...

---

#### What I have done so far.

I have been doing the following thing:

```
    private Rectangle WinBar
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle(Location.X, Location.Y, Width, 31);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && WinBar.Contains(e.Location))
            Console.WriteLine("Being dragged!");
    }
```

My purpouse is that if the `IF-statment` is true I will call an `EventHandler`.

---

#### My main questions

But, for now, I can't figure this out, because of the following reasons:

- If I move the `Form` to the upper left corner of the screen **negative values** appear. I suppose this is not a problem, but I don't know why `e.Location` **is not equal to** `(0, 0)` if I put the Form in exact corner.
- **When my mouse is over the WinForm Bar nothing appears**, but if I move the mouse under (like 30 pixels to the left and 50 px to the bottom) the console goes crazy.
- Why there isn't a native `EventHandler` for this case?

---

#### Why I used 31 pixels for the WinBar height

I have checked that `WinForms` when `FormBorderStyle` property is set to `FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle` or `Fixed3D` or `FixedSingle` or `Sizable` is 31 pixels, as this image show us:

[image: evidence]

The evidence is on the size of the selection on **MSPaint**.

But I not use how to measure it for example for `FixedToolWindow` or `SizableToolWindow`. (Maybe I should use a ternary condition)

---

So, there are several uncertain things, and I don't know if this is the better way to do it. So, any help would be great!

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to sense when the whole form is moved around the screen, right?

If so, use the Form´s LocationChanged event and examine the Form´s Location property to see where you are...

**Edit** to add example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsTestMove
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loc = this.Location;
            this.Text = loc.X + " " + loc.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I have to say to you that this event doesn't exists... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean, it surely exists! See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/e0xc63zd(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

Comment: You understood perfectly my question. But the resource given is for a Control that has AllowDrop set to true.

Comment: In my test it doesn´t make any difference if the form ahs the allow drop set to "true" or "false"... I think we are talking different things here? I used an event handler for the form, just to make that clear.

Comment: Sorry, we were talking about the same thing. But my mistake was that I believe that LocationChanged was only available for Control, but this impossible because Form is inhertied from it. That was because Intelisense didn't help me, because I was trying to set a value for LocationChanged in a static method, so you're right! This is a good oportunity for you to learn some extra reputation, I hope you do the same! Good bye.